# How do I reference one method in another? And why am I only able to define a variable in an if statement once?

Tags: java, android

```
public void toggleoperator(View v){
    ToggleButton oprtoggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.operatortoggle);
    boolean add = ((oprtoggle.isChecked()));
    if (add){
        oprtoggle.setTextOn("Add");
        int x = 1;

    } else {
        oprtoggle.setTextOff("Subtract");
        int x = -1;
    }


public void sumNumbers(View v){
    EditText input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input1);
    int calc1 =  Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(input1.getText()));
    EditText input2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input2);
    int calc2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(input2.getText()));
    int totaladd = calc1 + calc2;
    int totalsubtract = calc1 - calc2;
    if (add) {
        String result = String.valueOf(totaladd);
    } else {
        String result = String.valueOf(totalsubtract);
    }
    EditText output1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.output);
    output1.setText(result);
    }
```

I'm trying to get the above code to work. For one, I want to reference the boolean 'add' from the first method to the second method, how would I go about doing that? Also, I'm getting a 'Not a statement' error on this line

```
String result = String.valueOf(totalsubtract);
```

Help? And please explain too, otherwise I won't learn!

Comment: I'd take a step back and learn some Java basics before going any further. You can't reference a method's local variables from anywhere else--they're variables local to the method they're defined in. Also, you cannot reference variables defined in a block outside of the block. This is basic Java Scoping 101. Without knowing the basics things are going to take exponentially longer.

Comment: any good resources you can suggest? I feel like I learn a lot better if I code myself and get help along the way, and reading documentation on Java just confuses me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reference a method from another method you simply call the second method from the first one.

```
public void methodA(){
    methodB();
    Object o = new Object();
    methodC(o);
}

public void methodB(){
    //do something
}

public void methodC(Object o){
    o.doSomething();
}
```

Fields in Java have something called scope. The scope of a local field, as in defined inside a method or a loop, is exhausted when the method or the loop is over.
If you want to make a field accessible to the whole Class, you need to define it outside methods, you do not need to initialize the field immediately, you can delegate it to constructor or methods.

```
public class Clazz{
    public int i;
    public Clazz(int i){
        this.i = i;
    }

    public void setI(int i){
        this.i = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to access a variable in another method, it won't work because of "scope".

Basically, if you define a variable inside a method, it will only be available TO that method. One work around is to define the variables outside the method, so that all the methods in that class can access them. Another solution would be to "return" the variable, so that other methods can access them by calling your method.

I suggest reading this:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

and this:http://java.about.com/od/s/g/Scope.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you want your "add" boolean to be accessible from both methods, it should be created as a class variable, rather than a function variable OR it should be passed via parameters to the second function.

```
class Clazz {

    //Declares the variable at class scope (this should be false by default)
    boolean add;

    //Sets the value of the "add" boolean
    public void toggle () {
        add = toggle.isChecked();
    }

    public void secondMethod () {
        int diff = 0;
        if (add) {
            //make "diff" a positive value, based on what's entered.
        } else {
            //make "diff" a negative value, based on what's entered.
        }
        Display.setText(new String(diff));
    }
}
```

I will not say that this is the nicest example code ever, however it is functional and SHOULD resolve your issues.

I would like to note, in addition, that it is trivial that the addition and subtraction both be done if only one of these is needed.  This is why I had changed the way that the calculations come out.